# PHP Export to Excel XLS Shows column in one line

Tags: php

I tried exporting php table in excel format 'xls', But exported data is showing in one column.

Code tried so far:

```
<?php
    $host="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $dbname="data-crypter";
    $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password,$dbname); 

        $sql_data="select * from users";
        $result_data=$con->query($sql_data);
        $results=array();
    $filename = "Webinfopen.xls"; // File Name
    header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename);
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");


    $flag = false;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_data)) {
        if (!$flag) {
            // display field/column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
        }
        echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Why do people always believe that they can write a better csv exporter than PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function?

Comment: And you're not writing an Excel xls format file, just a csv file that you're  calling an xls file

Comment: But as you're using tabs as a separator, and MS Excel assumes comma or semi-colon separator (depending on MS Excel's locale settings) then that's why MS Excel puts everything in the one column